Unable to find settings in assets in Unity XR Development
I am trying to create a AR app using unity, I was following a tutorial in youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJAO6jDYljs
I can't find the Settings folder in Assets folder, also there is no renderer settings.
I am new to unity as well as XR Development.



I tried looking for solution online but couldn't find any.
Looking for tips as well.

If you don't have the Assets/Settings folder, you likely created a project that is using the legacy Built-in Renderer Pipeline.
Instead, you need to create a Universal 3D project. URP (Universal Rendering Pipeline) is typically used for VR/XR development.
You can install the URP packages to your exisiting project. But since you are new to Unity, it should be easier for you to create a new project from Unity Hub.
You need the one that's called Universal 3D:

